# strategy for REST API in go

Tags: database, rest, go

In my database, each row corresponds to a struct

```
type datum struct{
    Id *string `json:"task_id"`
    Status *string `json:"status"`
    AccountId *string `json:"account_id"`
    .... // many more fields, all of pointer types
}
```

On the webpage, the user can query on several fields of datum (say `account_id` and `status`). The server will return all data that satisfy the query with a projection of the fields (say `Id`, `account_id` and `status`).

Right now, I wrote a HTTP handler to

Extract the query as a datum object from the request:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
condition := datum{} 
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &condition)
```

Use the partially filled datum object to query the database, only the non-nil fields translate to `SELECT ... WHERE ..=..`. The query result is saved in `query_result []datum`

Write the `query_result` into json object for reply:

```
reply := map[string]interface{}{
            "reply": query_result,
        }
data, err := json.Marshal(reply)
```

The problem is that in the reply many of the fields are nil, but I still send them, which is wasteful. On the other hand, I don't want to change the datum struct to include `omitempty` tag because in the database a value entry has all fields non-nil.

- In this case, shall I define a new struct just for the reply? Is there a way to define this new struct using `datum` struct, instead of hard code one?
- Is there a better design for this query feature?

Comment: I find it confusing that while your database fields are all non-null, you still have "...in the reply many of the fields are nil...", i.e. some values for your would-be query where not set. Unless I miss some point, there's an issue with business-logic. Please elaborate.

Comment: @mpmlj After the query, there is a projection, I only return say 3 of the fields back to user instead of all fields. In the current implementation, I return the datum struct with many nil fields. Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, with choice depending what is more wasteful/expensive in your particular case:

1. Just use pointers+omitempty in the original struct.
2. Prepare a custom response object. But you'll need to copy/convert the values from the original struct into its export version.
3. Write a custom marshaller, that will be exploring your struct and creating an export-ready variant, this way being more dynamic/automatic that #1.

While #1 needs no comments, and #2 to some extend covered by Gepser above, here's how you can address this with a custom marshaller (the idea is to re-assemble your output skipping nil fields):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "encoding/json"
    "reflect"
)

type datum struct {
    Id        *string `json:"task_id"`
    Status    *string `json:"status"`
    AccountId *string `json:"account_id"`
}

type Response struct {
    Reply []datum `json:"reply"`
}

func main() {

    var query_result []datum

    // mocking a query result with records with nil fields
    val_id_a := "id-a"
    val_status := "status-b"
    d1 := datum{
        Id:     &val_id_a,
        Status: &val_status,
    }

    query_result = append(query_result, d1)

    val_id_b := "id-b"
    val_account_id := "account-id-b"
    d2 := datum{
        Id:        &val_id_b,
        AccountId: &val_account_id,
    }

    query_result = append(query_result, d2)

    reply := &Response{
        Reply: query_result,
    }

    data, err := json.Marshal(reply)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", string(data))
}

// MarshalJSON is a custom JSON marshaller implementation for Response object.
func (r *Response) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    a := struct {
        Reply []map[string]interface{} `json:"reply"`
    }{}

    for _, v := range r.Reply {
        a.Reply = append(a.Reply, converter(v))
    }

    return json.Marshal(a)
}

// converter converts a struct into a map, skipping fields with nil values.
func converter(in interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    out := make(map[string]interface{})
    v := reflect.ValueOf(in)

    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        f := v.Type().Field(i)
        tag := f.Tag.Get("json")
        if tag != "" && !v.Field(i).IsNil() {
            out[tag] = v.Field(i).Interface()
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

Comment: Your 3rd way is what I wanted. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I suggest (is the one I use) is the `new struct` with `omitempty` tag, for example:

```
type datumResponse struct{
    Id *string `json:"task_id,omitempty"`
    Status *string `json:"status,omitempty"`
    AccountId *string `json:"account_id,omitempty"`
    .... // many more fields
}
```

and there is no option to write your new `struct` using the fields of the old one if there is not substructs or you don't write an array of structs.